# How to use AsyncStorage in App.tsx so that commands are fired in correct order

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm struggling for a long time with the `AsyncStorage` and finding a way to use it in my project. My issue is that I'm not able to fire it in the right time. In the following example I need the token to be filled before the following command (here for demonstration I use `console.log(2)`) is fired.

Also, to mention, this is the App.tsx, so I'm not able to use `useState` or `componentDidMount` which would solve my issue.

Example:

```
console.log(1)
const token = AsyncStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN).then((token) => {
  console.log(token)
  if (token != null) {
    return token
  }
});
console.log(2)
```

So what I would like to have is:

```
1
ojh324rfoj32n4t243to2n
2
```

but I get:

```
1
2
ojh324rfoj32n4t243to2n
```

How to control the `async await` so it is safe to use the `token` variable?

I also would **not** like to use the `callback` function, as I would then need to put everything in there, which I think would not work without issues.

Future usage (pseudo code):

```
const token = AsyncStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN).then((token) => {
  console.log(token)
  if (token != null) {
    return token
  }
});
use(token)...
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to control the async await so it is safe to use the token variable?

You can use an `async` function with an `await` like this

```js
async function example() {
  console.log(1)
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  console.log(token)
  console.log(2)
}
```

`await` will work here because `getItem` returns a Promise object. You can await any promise as an alternative of `.then` or a callback function.

Comment: That's clear, but I need that token available out of the function example =) How to get that done?

Comment: Depends on how you want to use it. One option is to return the token and await for the value from the parent scope, but that will require the parent scope to be async as well. It is also possible to store the token somewhere else, such as a component state or ref.

Comment: As I said, in the App.tsx you do not have a state, and also no component. But how do I return it in my case? I added my future usage above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it with rewriting my `App` from a `function` to a `React component`.

So what I started with was the `function App`. Here we had no chance to use `componentDidMount`:

```
export default function App() {
```

So I converted the `function` to a `Component` that looks like the following:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
```

And I added the `render() {` as it's needed in a component. After that I moved everything directly under that `render` what has been before above my `function App` line.

Now I added the `state` as well as the `componentDidMount`. This is important to precheck if the App has already been loaded. It also prevents the `App` to reload again at any time later on. So that should work properly, until the user might reload the browser. Anyways this worked out as it now only once loads the `authtoken` into the states and that the `render` finished the initialization of the needed variables.

Here is the important code after the changes:

```
export default class App extends React.Component { 
  state = {
    authtoken: null, 
    isLoading: true, 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN).then((currentToken) => {
      if (currentToken != null) {
        this.setState({ 
          authtoken: currentToken,
          isLoading: false,
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({ 
          authtoken: '',
          isLoading: false,
        })
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let { authtoken, isLoading } = this.state
    if (isLoading == null) {
      return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>
    } else {
      ...
```